# Is it possible for someone to hack my SWF by accessing one of its function

Tags: actionscript-3, security

In my SWF, I have a function that automatically runs at a certain time.
The user must not run that function or change a timer variable, so is he able to do it with some work ?

Comment: We would need a bit more information. What does the function do? And what do you mean by hack?

Comment: the function allows an audio netstream to be received.
the user gets that audio netstream after 5 minutes and must not have it less than 5 minutes.
I mean by Hack: the user tries to uncompile to SWF and gets the function name & contents

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All code that runs on the client side must be considered as insecure and hackable. Period.

Comment: +1 Yep - 100% true. If you give the user the code, a malicious user can break it, reverse engineer it and change it.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is write your code, google search for uncompilers, and see what they produce, more often than not, you get very readable code, and if u have defined strings, then the user would most likely be able to see them.

I suggest your switch to server side code, as this is more secure, however it is ran on the server end not the user end, so it takes more processing power.

Comment: even if the user see's the code, how they force call a function on a .swf file?

Comment: The function most likely contains urls and credentials that Younes has hard coded into the function.